# Load extension into React Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

Im trying to load extensions in this React [Viewer](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components/blob/main/client/components/Viewer.jsx). It should be possible to pass them via props, as show this viewer snippet:

```
      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, async function () {
        const extensionsToLoad = props.extensions;

        const extensionsWithConfig = [];
        const extensionsWithoutConfig = [];

        for (let key in extensionsToLoad) {
            const config = extensionsToLoad[key];
            if (Object.keys(config).length === 0) {
                extensionsWithoutConfig.push(key);
            } else {
                extensionsWithConfig.push(key);
            }
        }

        const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerDomRef.current, {
            extensions: extensionsWithoutConfig,
            disabledExtensions: props.disabledExtensions || {},
        });
```

However i registered an extension and it is unrecognized.

The extension :

```
window.Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('DrawBoundsToolExtension', DrawBoundsToolExtension);
```

And how i pass it :

```
function App() {
return (
    <div className="App">
        <Viewer
            getToken={renewExpiredToken}
            docUrn={urn}
            extensions={'DrawBoundsToolExtension'}
        />
    </div>
);
```

}

i get this error in chrome devtools : `Uncaught (in promise) Extension not found: 0. Has it been registered(1)?`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you look at how the **BaseApp.jsx** pass extension to the `viewer` component :     `<Viewer env={env} docUrn={docUrn} api={api} onViewerInitialized={onViewerInitialized} onModelLoaded={onModelLoaded} getToken={getToken} extensions={{ "Autodesk.Viewing.ZoomWindow": {}, "Autodesk.DataVisualization": {}, }} geomIndex={props.geomIndex} />`. I think you must pass an object instead of a simple string. As you can see in the code, the `viewer` takes all the **objects keys** to get the list of extensions to load. Can you try that ?

Comment: One more thing to check: did you import your extension js file into your viewer app by using `import` keyword or `<script src="DrawBoundsToolExtension,js"></script>`?

Comment: Extension not found: Autodesk.DataVisualization. Has it been registered(1) i am also getting this while using v7.7.1 @EasonKang

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this issue on my side. Could you check if any error shows up when loading the `Autodesk.DataVisualization` ext?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/36F2M.png